# Getting Output of Array in Predetermined way

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 

    echo "<div class='listing'>";
        print $row['uUName'] . '</strong><br />' .
        '<strong>' . $row['listTitle'] . '</strong><br />' .
        $arr = explode(':', $row['diff']);
        echo "{$arr[0]} hours, {$arr[1]} minutes ago";
    echo "</div>";
    }
    unset($sth1);   
    ?>
```

**Outputting**

```
Array01 hours, 48 minutes ago
Array04 hours, 01 minutes ago
```

How do I get RID of :
Array01
Array04 
from the beginning and just be left with:

```
01 hours, 48 minutes ago
04 hours, 01 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$result = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row)
{ 

echo "<div class='listing'>";
    print $row['uUName'] . '</strong><br />' .
    '<strong>' . $row['listTitle'] . '</strong><br />';
    $arr = explode(':', $row['diff']);
    echo "{$arr[0]} hours, {$arr[1]} minutes ago";
echo "</div>";
}
unset($sth1);   
?>
```

Notice line 8, where I've removed your '. and replaced it with '; in the end.